# How to exit holy mode and get back to evil mode spacemacs?

Tags: spacemacs

I had to get into `customize-mode` to try something out and I am stuck in holy mode and don't have way to get out of it. Is there a way to get back to evil mode once you have entered holy mode?

`M-m t E-h` seems to work, but is there are better way?

Answer (score 14):

The default keybinding to toggle `holy-mode` in Spacemacs is `M-m t E e` (or `SPC t E e` when in `evil-mode`).

If you need to do this a lot, you can of course bind the function `holy-mode` to a shorter sequence of keys, using `global-set-key` (put this in your `.spacemacs` file):

```
(global-set-key (kbd "<f9>") 'holy-mode) ; toggle holy-mode using the <f9> key
```

---

You can also switch out of the `evil-emacs-state` using `C-z`. When I try this in `customize-mode` it switches from the (blue cursor) Emacs-keybindings to the (yellow cursor) Spacemacs/vim normal mode bindings.

Answer (score 12):

The easiest way is `M-x evil-exit-emacs-state` (or sometimes with `C-z`)

Comment: This has no effect for me.